# How can I override the date_hierarchy function for a single ModelAdmin?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I would like to set `date_hierarchy` on a ModelAdmin to a field on a related model, for example:

```
date_hierarchy = 'item__menu__date'
```

This is not possible in Django 1.9, but will be possible in Django 1.11. The code for the 1.11 feature already exists. (ref. [1](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19963) [2](https://github.com/django/django/pull/6563) [3](https://github.com/django/django/pull/6563/files#diff-2949e497e8480d99bb7e46adaf8b3f91))

As far as I can tell, overriding just `def date_hierarchy(cl)` from `django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py` for a single ModelAdmin will make this possible for that ModelAdmin.

I've found writeups on overriding templatetags, but these tend to focus on HTML files. Is it possible to override the `date_hierarchy()` function in the context of a single ModelAdmin? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is not possible.

Instead, I [monkey-patched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the changes into our local copy of the library, and accepted the [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) associated with this approach.